# Can I install 16GB RAM on quad-core MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I'm planning to buy a new MacBook Pro with quad-core. And I want to install 16GB on it. But there is only 8GB options on Apple's website. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Apple the answer is no, but OWC has [tested it](http://blog.macsales.com/9283-owc-announces-industry%E2%80%99s-first-16gb-ram-upgrade-for-latest-apple-macbook-pro-models) and found that there are no issues putting 16GB (2x8GB) in the latest generation MacBook Pro. The upgrade doesn't come cheap, though - at this time 2x8GB modules will set you back $1599.

http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/1333DDR3S16P/

Comment: 16 GB is way too expensive... maybe in a few months for my new mbp.

Comment: The price for the 16 Gb kit has come down dramatically since it was introduced back in March or April. It used to be 1700$ + and now is less than 800$. Just wait a few months and it'll be affordable. I myself am waiting for a 500$ price point before doing the move...

Comment: And as of this writing the price has dropped to $320.00

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Currently $180 from NewEgg.
I just installed a Corsair 16GB matched pair (2x8GB 1333MHz DDR3 CL9) on an Early 2011 13" MacBook Pro (i7 2.7GHz). Running Great!
Corsair part number CMSO16GX3M2A1333C9. NewEgg link:
http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233217

BTW - Mid 2010 MacBook Pro models will NOT boot with this 2x8GB memory.
(they will boot with 8GB (2x4GB) 1333MHz memory but see it as 1067MHz).

Answer (score 2):

(No, it has two slots and a maximum of 8 GB ([Apple page](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro?mco=MTM3NjU5MzU)).  Perhaps you are thinking of the desktop i7 which has 3 or 6 slots, for a maximum of 12 or 24 GB.  I checked newegg, there aren't 8 GB DDR-3 SO DIMMs.

Answer (score 1):

[Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820144555&Tpk=GeIL%208GB%20204-Pin%20DDR3%20SO-DIMM%20DDR3%201333%20%28PC3%2010660) lists 8GB sticks. You could buy two and get a 16GB setup.